# AWS Lambda Node.js6.10 '/06'のエスケープがうまくいかない

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

AWS Lambdaから、curlを使ってFTP接続をしようとしています。
しかし、pwが'\06'始まりなのが災いしてか、PWを正しく引き渡すことができず、
Access denied: 530"になってしまいます。
（コマンドプロンプトから実行すると接続でることを確認しました。）

一部ですが、コードは以下の通りです。

```
var com = 'curl --globoff -u testuser:\06testpw ${url}'
const child = exec(com, function(error) {
  context.done(error, 'Process complete!')});
```

※実際には、${url}に接続先を指定しています。

・上記の場合、'testuser:06testpw'が引き渡されます。
・’testuser:'+'\06'+'testpw'とすると、'testuser:testpw'が引き渡されます。
・'\\06testpw'を指定すると、'\\06testpw'そのままになってしまいます。

Encodeなどいろいろ試しましたが、うまくいきませんでした。。

お力添えいただきたく、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: javascriptの特殊文字に「/xxxx」 （xxxxは8進数）とあり、0始まりであるために8進数とみなされているのでしょうか。。

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types

Comment: 文字列リテラルで \ 自体を表すには、2つ重ねて \\ とします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。投稿に誤りがありましたので修正しました。\\を指定すると、\\が渡ってしまいます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`child_process.exec`](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.10/api/child_processes.html#child_process.exec)は

> Runs a command in a shell and buffers the output.

とのことですので、`exec`に渡した値が改めてシェルによって再度解析されます。`curl`に引数`--globoff`, `-u`, `testuser:\06testpw`, `${url}`を渡したいのであれば`exec`には

```
curl --globoff -u testuser:\\06testpw ${url}
```

を渡す必要があり、JavaScriptコードでは

```
var com = 'curl --globoff -u testuser:\\\\06testpw ${url}';
```

と2重エスケープすればいいのではないでしょうか？

---

> '\06testpw'を指定すると、'\06testpw'そのままになってしまいます。

これは本当でしょうか？ 単に成功しないことと`\\06testpw`になることは別問題ですが、どのように確認されたのでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます、二重エスケープでできました！

>\\06testpwになる
エラーレスポンスから確認しましたが、関係なかったですね。。失礼しました。

Comment: @nnng 解決したのであれば回答を承認しクローズしてください。引き続き質問をオープンし続けられるのでしたら、解決したい点、回答を求めたい点を明確にしてください。

Comment: すみません、なぜか承認もクローズもできませんのでお待ちください